# Finding the Density of Y

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Let X be a random variable having a normal density and consider the random variable $Y=e^X$. Then Y has a log normal density. Find the density of $Y$.

I am not exactly sure how to show this but below is what I have started

$$F(Y)=Pr(Y \le y) = Pr(e^X \le y) = Pr(X \le log(y))$$

But here is where I am not sure to go. I have seen some change of variable methods but I am not sure if those apply. What is throwing me off is that X is given to be Normal.

I Know the answer is

$$f(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi y}}e^\frac{-log^2(y)}{2}$$

Comment: The traditional change of variables can be used, note that $e^x$ is monotone hence it fulfills all the conditions of the theorem.

Comment: From the equation you derived, you have obtained $F_Y(y) = F_X(\ln y)$ already. Now differentiate both sides with respect to $y$ to obtain the required density $f_Y(y)$.

Comment: @BGM So I guess what confuses me is that $F_Y(y)=e^x$ ? If i am going to try to integrate I don't know what to be integrating.

Comment: The $y$ in the denominator also has me confused as to how it has gotten there.